# How does Nix's "callPackage" call functions defined without an ellipsis?

Tags: nix, nixpkgs

To call a Nix function that uses set destructuring, you need to pass it a set with *exactly* the keys it requires, no more and no less:

```
nix-repl> ({ a }: a) { a = 4; b = 5; }
error: anonymous function at (string):1:2 called with unexpected argument ‘b’, at (string):1:1
```

The exception to this is if the function's argument list contains an ellipsis at the end:

```
nix-repl> ({ a, ... }: a) { a = 4; b = 5; }
4
```

However, most of the packages in [nixpkgs](https://github.com/nixos/nixpkgs) consist of a `default.nix` file containing a function which is *not* defined with this ellipsis. Yet, somehow when you use `callPackage`, it manages to call these functions and pass them only the arguments that they need. How is this implemented?

Comment: For anyone wondering where `callPackage` is implemented (and how to find lambda definitions), see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56124590/1498178

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a reflection primop, that can deconstruct function argument:

```
nix-repl> __functionArgs ( { x ? 1, y }: x )
{ x = true; y = false; }
```

[`callPackage`](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/a6218c058b3e994779147dd7286606c750be7d73/lib/customisation.nix#L96) then iterates over those attribute names, fetches required packages and constucts the attrset of packages, that is fed later to called function.

Here's a simple example:

```
nix-repl> callWithExtraArgs = f: args:
            let
              args' = __intersectAttrs (__functionArgs f) args;
            in
              f args'

nix-repl> callWithExtraArgs ({ x }: x + 1) { x = 4; y = 7; }
5
```

---

To browse Nix primops, go to [15.5. Built-in Functions](https://nixos.org/manual/nix/stable/#ssec-builtins) in the [Nix manual](https://nixos.org/manual/nix/stable/) (or see [the docs of the unstable branch](https://nixos.org/manual/nix/unstable/expressions/builtins.html)).

Comment: Initially I added the line "_`__functionArgs` is the same as `builtins.functionArgs`_" to the edit above because both evaluate to `«primop»` in `nix repl`, but [the comment and code in `trivial.nix`](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/8aca4a8fa7b053e67c7200f426826cd93afd92a8/lib/trivial.nix#L310) made me unsure about that statement. (The link shows `setFunctionArgs` as well because can't wrap my head around its seemingly circular definition..) Same goes to `__intersectAttrs` and `builtins.intersectAttrs`.

Comment: @toraritte they are same, it is just lib.nix *adds* __functionArgs attr to mimic __functionArgs builtin. It used to "pass" actual __functionArgs result down to consumers, because builtin __functionArgs only works on top-most function args. Yeah, mind wrapping