# Where is `callPackage` defined in the Nixpkgs repo (or how to find Nix lambda definitions in general)?

Tags: nix, nixpkgs

Found a lot of sources describing `callPackage` and some of its internals, but none that refers to it's location. It's like the best kept secret of Nix, and the manuals even seem to be actively avoiding the topic. I could find it given time, but it's a huge repo.

Resources:

- [How does Nix's “callPackage” call functions defined without an ellipsis? (Stackoverlow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46083266/how-does-nixs-callpackage-call-functions-defined-without-an-ellipsis)
- [Nix Pills, Chapter 13. Callpackage Design Pattern](https://nixos.org/nixos/nix-pills/callpackage-design-pattern.html)
  Nix

---

The answer actually points to `callPackageWith` function in `customisation.nix`, but [`callPackage` itself is defined elsewhere](https://discourse.nixos.org/t/where-is-callpackage-defined-exactly-part-2/12524).

Comment: Just learned that there is also a `callPackages` function (from [Nixpkgs#36354](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/36354) issue), and basically both are undocumented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Despite the lambda output from the other answer, I believe the original value of `callPackage` is actually defined inside of `pkgs/top-level/splice.nix`, [link here](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/803b5ff95a4196ddb77fe2e8371999aae67195f7/pkgs/top-level/splice.nix#L143)

The reason the path in the lambda doesn't return that^ position is because nixpkgs does some absolutely insane recurisve computation. My understanding is that `pkgs` is replaced over and over (bootstrapped), and the attributes on `pkgs` (like   `callPackages`) are replaced multiple times. If you're familiar with [fixed point combinators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator) in mathematics, like the Y-Combinator, that is effectively what Nixpkgs is applying until the pkgs stablizes. So `pkgs.callPackage` is actually some random/dynamic function-argument instead of an attribute that is set directly. And that dynamic function argument is what the lambda-path refers to.

> It's like the best kept secret of Nix

I've been reading the source code for 3 years, and it took me at least 5 hours of chopping up a [minimized version of nixpkgs](https://discourse.nixos.org/t/deeply-understanding-the-nixpkgs-repo-with-nix-trace/24868/3?u=jeff-hykin) (which was a project on its own) in order to figure out that `callPackage` was actually coming from `pkgs/top-level/splice.nix`. And finding where it is defined isn't even half the battle for really understanding where it's coming from. So yeah, I'd say its a pretty well kept secret and might still be a secret after this answer since I can still barely claim to understand it myself.

Answer (score 15):

`nix repl` can tell you the location where a lambda is defined.

```
$ nix repl
Welcome to Nix version 2.2.2. Type :? for help.

nix-repl> pkgs = import <nixpkgs> {}

nix-repl> pkgs.callPackage
«lambda @ /nix/store/9hffpjaa2a7djl19ncky7zcvlhyj76dn-nixos-19.03.172396.d740b2ee855/nixos/lib/customisation.nix:108:31»
```

where the part up to and including `nixos` is my `<nixpkgs>`, thus giving you the answer: [`lib/customisation.nix` line 108](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/f02bbfc0eab7ec86426f0e277acbd9aee1d96495/lib/customisation.nix#L108).

In some cases, it can also report the location of an attribute.

```
nix-repl> builtins.unsafeGetAttrPos "callPackage" pkgs
{ column = 3; file = "~/src/nixpkgs/pkgs/top-level/splice.nix"; line = 143; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the added bonus of showing how to find lambda definitions!

Comment: Just found the `nix repl '<nixpkgs>'` shortcut to import all Nixpkgs expression on repl startup.

Comment: one line: `nix repl '<nixpkgs>' <<< pkgs.callPackage`

Comment: On the current version of nix (2.12), the path in that lambda actually leads to `callPackagesWith` not `callPackages`. I still can't find anywhere in the nixpkgs source where the top-level `callPackage` attribute is actually assigned (there are many non-top-level definitions). My guess as to the true place is either inside of `makeScope` or `makeScopeWithSplicing` (both inside of lib/customisation.nix) but I'm not sure which is the true source, or how it ends up being added to `pkgs`. So for me this question is still unanswered

Comment: @JeffHykin, I've updated the answer with a new technique. The `pkgs.callPackage` attribute is defined in `pkgs/top-level/splice.nix`

Answer (score 1):

Before flakes I used `nix edit nixpkgs.callPackage` and with flakes `nix edit nixpkgs\#callPackage`.

And it works regardless if it lambda or not. E.g. `nix edit nixpkgs\#nix.meta`

Comment: Never heard of `nix edit`, and just checked out all subcommands with `nix --help`, thanks! It didn't work for `callPackage` however, even though `nix edit nixpkgs.hello` (or any other  package) did. (I have version 2.3.10.)

Comment: BTW, you don't need the backslash in `nixpkgs#nix.meta` -- `#` is only a comment character in POSIX-family shells when it's at the beginning of a word; in all other positions it's literal.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, I use zsh and it treats `#` for filename globbing. E.g. `echo /bo#t` echoes `/boot`.

Comment: Ah. (Glad I hedged with the "POSIX-family" qualifier; zsh is deliberately noncompliant).

Comment: @ony You should alias `nix` to `noglob nix`!