# Why is `functionArgs` implemented twice? (i.e, as a primop and in `lib`)

Tags: nix

Trying to understand `callPackage`, so looked up [its implementation](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/a6218c058b3e994779147dd7286606c750be7d73/lib/customisation.nix#L96-L121) where it uses `lib.functionArgs` ([source](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/8aca4a8fa7b053e67c7200f426826cd93afd92a8/lib/trivial.nix#L334)), but there is already a `builtins.functionArgs` primop, an alias of `__functionArgs` ([implemented in C](https://github.com/NixOS/nix/blob/c8937ba9f34174a0ddeb1137b523e31c4acfb6af/src/libexpr/primops.cc#L2259-L2285)).

`lib.functionArgs` is defined as

```hs
   /* Extract the expected function arguments from a function.
      This works both with nix-native { a, b ? foo, ... }: style
      functions and functions with args set with 'setFunctionArgs'. It
      has the same return type and semantics as builtins.functionArgs.
      setFunctionArgs : (a → b) → Map String Bool.
   */

    functionArgs = f: f.__functionArgs or (builtins.functionArgs f);
```

and the `__functionArgs` attribute above is coming from `setFunctionArgs` ([source](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/8aca4a8fa7b053e67c7200f426826cd93afd92a8/lib/trivial.nix#L312-L326)):

```hs
  /* Add metadata about expected function arguments to a function.
     The metadata should match the format given by
     builtins.functionArgs, i.e. a set from expected argument to a bool
     representing whether that argument has a default or not.
     setFunctionArgs : (a → b) → Map String Bool → (a → b)

     This function is necessary because you can't dynamically create a
     function of the { a, b ? foo, ... }: format, but some facilities
     like callPackage expect to be able to query expected arguments.
  */

  setFunctionArgs = f: args:
    {
      __functor = self: f;
      __functionArgs = args;
    };
```

I understand what `setFunctionArgs` does, and the comment above its declaration tells why it is necessary, but I can't understand it; both clauses of that sentence are clear but not sure how the first statement prevents the second one to be achieved (without `setFunctionArgs`, that is).

[danbst also tried to elucidate this further](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46083266/how-does-nixs-callpackage-call-functions-defined-without-an-ellipsis#:%7E:text=they%20are%20same),

> `lib.nix` adds `__functionArgs` attr to mimic `__functionArgs` builtin. It
> used to "pass" actual `__functionArgs` result down to consumers, because
> builtin `__functionArgs` only works on top-most function args

but not sure what the "consumers" are, and couldn't unpack the last clause (i.e., "*builtin `__functionArgs` only works on top-most function args*"). Is this a reference to the fact that Nix functions are curried, and

```
nix-repl> g = a: { b, c }: "lofa"

nix-repl> builtins.functionArgs g
{ }
```

?

`lib.functionArgs` also doesn't solve this problem, but I'm probably off the tracks at this point.

---

**Notes to self**

`__functor` is documented in the Nix manual under [**Sets**](https://nixos.org/manual/nix/stable/#idm140737321995552).

```
$ nix repl '<nixpkgs>'
Welcome to Nix version 2.3.6. Type :? for help.

Loading '<nixpkgs>'...
Added 11530 variables.

nix-repl> f = { a ? 7, b }: a + b

nix-repl> set_f = lib.setFunctionArgs f { b = 9; }

nix-repl> set_f
{ __functionArgs = { ... }; __functor = «lambda @ /nix/store/16blhmppp9k6apz41gjlgr0arp88awyb-nixos-20.03.3258.86fa45b0ff1/nixos/lib/trivial.nix:318:19»; }

nix-repl> set_f.__functionArgs
{ b = 9; }

nix-repl> set_f set_f.__functionArgs
16

nix-repl> set_f { a = 27; b = 9; }
36
```

Comment: Interesting. In some other cases of duplication the `lib` implementation came first, or adds features the builtin one doesn't have, but I haven't ever looked into this one (and it sounds like you've done enough research to catch obvious cases of either of those possibilities).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lib.functionArgs` wraps `builtins.functionArgs` in order to provide reflective access to generic functions.

This supports reflection with `builtins.functionArgs`:

```hs
f = { a, b, c }: #...
```

Now consider the [eta abstraction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40617754/what-is-eta-abstraction-in-lambda-calculus-used-for) of the same function:

```hs
f' = attrs: f attrs
```

This does not support reflection with `builtins.functionArgs`. With `setFunctionArgs`, you can restore that information, as long as you also use `lib.functionArgs`.

I recommend to avoid reflection because everything that I've seen implemented with it can be implemented without it. It expands the definition of a function to include what should normally be considered implementation details.
Anyway, the primary motivation seems to be `callPackage`, which *can* be implemented with normal attrset operations if you change all packages to add `...` as in `{ lib, stdenv, ... }:`. I do have a morbid interest in this misfeature that is function reflection, so if anyone finds another use case, please comment.

Comment: Are you saying to avoid using `callPackage`? I'm probably misinterpreting your penultimate sentence. Also, do you mean by "_the primary motivation seems to be callPackage, which can be implemented with normal attrset operations_" that one can skip using `callPackage` altogether? If yes, do you have an example repo by any chance? Sorry, just getting my feet wet.

Comment: No problem. You don't need to avoid `callPackage` at all. It's idiomatic and it does some useful behind the scenes trickery that could also have been achieved through other means. It seems to be implemented like this for historical reasons. Having to fix up the reflection info in some advanced cases is the only significant cost I'm aware of.